# Put Enum into array without specify the Enum

Tags: c#, arrays

I want an array to store Enums without specify the Enum

```
public enum Gender{Male, Female}

public enum CountryName{America, Russia, China}
```

I tried that:

```
Enum[] info = new Enum[]{Gender, CountryName};
```

but it doesn't work:
`'Gender' and 'CountryName' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

What I am trying to do:
I am trying To get A Random Enum From That List

```
Random RandomEnum = new Random();
RandomEnum.Next(0, 1);

info[RandomEnum]
```

Comment: How do you intent to use such a thing ? Can you give some more context ? Maybe there's a reasonable alternative for your `Enum[]`.

Comment: I want to collect Enums to get Random Enum `info[RandomNumber]`

Comment: And do what with the value ? What is the actual problem you try to solve ? You should [edit] your quesrion and add all the info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add all the values of an enum to a collection, you must add the enum constants individually. This is easier to achieve with a `List<>` type.  It has a handy `AddRange` method. The enum values can be obtained with `Enum.GetValues<TEnum>()` and must be cast to items type of the list `Enum`.

```cs
var info = new List<Enum>();
info.AddRange(Enum.GetValues<Gender>().Cast<Enum>());
info.AddRange(Enum.GetValues<CountryName>().Cast<Enum>());
```

Test:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("All values:");
foreach (Enum e in info) {
    Console.WriteLine(e);    
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Random values:");
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Enum e = info[random.Next(info.Count)];
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Console output:

```
All values:
Male
Female
America
Russia
China

Random values:
Female
America
Russia
China
Female
America
America
Russia
Russia
Male
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in the error message, Gender and CountryName are types.
You cannot have an array of different types in c#.
What you can possibly do is storing the corresponding number in an array and later on cast the number to the proper enum type.

```cs
var arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryName));
var countryName = (CountryName)arr[0] // this would be America
```

Comment: do you mean that I should put Gender and CountryName Enum Elements in one Enum

Comment: @AnDrEw No, I mean if you want to store the enum values in an array, you can store the numeric values and later on the numbers can be casted to enum type.

Comment: However, in the given example, both Male and America have the value 0 - you cannot see to which enum they belong